# What is happening when I dissolve styrofoam in acetone? (And should this change temperature)

Tags: thermodynamics, polymers

I’ve completed a science experiment on endothermic and exothermic reactions in which I measured the temperature of solvents before adding solutes and measuring again. I found that dissolving styrofoam peanuts in acetone lowers the temperature of the acetone, but my book says that should not happen. Can anyone tell me what is happening when acetone dissolves polystyrene? I thought the reaction would be endothermic because the acetone is breaking down bonds in the styrofoam and using energy to do so and my book did not even explain anything about the reaction.

Comment: When you measure the lowering temperature of the acetone, have you found that it lowers specifically from the addition of the styrofoam? Or is the temperature of the acetone lowering by itself, due to evaporation? Try a small experiment of introducing additional surface area (maybe just some wads of paper towels) and seeing if that has the same temperature effect as the styrofoam. If so, maybe the acetone is just evaporating away and cooling off?

Comment: based on this link, I can say that the reaction you're seeing is that the acetone is dissolving the carbon-hydrogen bonds within the styrofoam: https://chem.utah.edu/_resources/documents/pdf/undergrad_program/Disappearing%20styrofoam%20no%20pics.pdf

Comment: I tried introducing surface area using some starch based peanuts, but nothing happened. For clarity, this reaction should use outside energy to break/weaken the polystyrene bonds, right? I know that polar solvents need some outside energy to break polar/ionic bonds. Is this the same for non polar solvents? Also thanks for the link! Very helpful.

Comment: Theoretical background:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flory%E2%80%93Huggins_solution_theory

Comment: @TylerM : dissolving C-H bonds ?!? What utter nonsense.

Comment: The question can be reformulated "What happens when bulk polystyrene is being dissolved in acetone?". Perform 2 parallel experiments, 1 with piece of bulk polystyrene ( used for many various boxes or disposable vessels ) and the other with about the same piece of PE/PP. Compare the cooling. As acetone significantly cools itself by intense evaporation what I bet is what you observe (or at least interferes with real dissolution cooling ).

Comment: Mmmm… This seems like a good idea. I’ll do it once I get more acetone. Actually I’ll just reuse the acetone I previously used. Also why did you say that the resolving of C-H bonds was nonsense? That is what’s happening, is it not? Polystyrene is just C and H so what else could it be?

Comment: @Karl why is it nonsense? The paper I linked makes sense to me. To quote the paper I linked: "Remember that likes dissolve likes. Acetone is a relatively non-polar solvent (as compared to water, which is highly polar), and Styrofoam is made from polystyrene and foam. Due to their similar polarities, acetone can dissolve the carbon-hydrogen bonds of Styrofoam. In return, the starch based peanuts are soluble in water because of the polar hydroxyl groups. Water and starch share the same properties (they are both highly polar), while water and Styrofoam have opposing properties."

Comment: Dissolution rather just breaks relatively weak van der Waals intermolecular forces, which consists of various ways of interaction between charges, permanent dipoles and induced dipoles.

Comment: *Styrofoam is made of polystyrene and foam* is incorrect. Foam is formed by polystyrene as solid structure, filled by closed or open ( based on the product type ) gaseous phase created by evaporation of foaming agent.

Comment: Could the experiment be flawed, in that your acetone is evaporating and as a result taking in more energy to go into acetone vapor than the dissolving of the polystyrene gives? You might want to repeat the experiment under pressure and enclosed, resulting in much less evaporation.

Comment: @Poutnik *or* by adding gas into a liquid which creates foam directly. This foam might, or might not, cure into a solid, depending on the chemical in question.

Comment: @Trish Sure, these are technological technicalities that are not very relevant the question. The relevant is interaction polystyrene - acetone. The captured gas is a bystander.

Comment: @TylerM I checked that text, and the rest of it makes sense for a low level undergrad course (my profs wouldn't have dared insulting us with such triviality, but never mind), but that phrase about the C-H bonds is just ridiculous. Every highschool kid should know that covalent bonds are not broken by such dissolution process. It seems Utah University chemistry 101 is taught by their retired caretaker.

Comment: I re-did the experiment and the more styrofoam I added the cooler the acetone got. The polystyrene remains the same in composition so what exactly is happening if not a chemical reaction/C-H bond breaking? And why does it absorb energy? 

P.s. This is for what I can only describe as a pre-introductory chemistry section of my physical science class.